# Accessing firebase children without uid

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is it possible to fetch a child from an object without the entire parent in Firebase
For example, a customer registry, where I need all the "name" fields, but I do not have the user "uid". ...

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alex's answer will work (with my comment for good measure).

But you should realize that this downloads all data of all users. There is no way in the Firebase Database to download just one property of each node. So if you want an efficient way to download just the list of names, you should keep precisely that in the database: a list of names.

```
usernames
  uid1: "Fernando"
  uid2: "Alex"
```

That way you can read just the list of names with:

```
DatabaseReference usernamesRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("usernames");

usernamesRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for (DataSnapshot childSnapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String uid = childSnapshot.getKey();
            String name = childSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip @FrankvanPuffelen , it helped a lot

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. Please use this code:

```
DatabaseReference yourRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("usuarios");

usersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String uId = (String) ds.getKey();
            String nome = ds.getChild("nome").getValue(String.class);
            list.add(nome);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
        throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

You first iterate to get those uid's and after that use them in the `DatabaseReference`.

Hope it helps.

Comment: The first listener will read all `usuarios`. The second listener is not needed, you can simply do `ds.getChild("nome").getValue(String.class)` in the loop.

Comment: And if in the case @AlexMamo I want to insert all the "name" inside a list gets like?

Comment: Than declare the `List` inside the `onDataChange()` method, otherwise it will be null.

Comment: Have an example please @AlexMamo ? I'm starting with this language and I'm having a lot of difficulties

Comment: How do I display this list outside DataChange @FrankvanPuffelen ?
For example ... I would like to create a method to retrieve a name list and return it to the end of the method ...